# Angular custom validator silently failing/not firing

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I need to verify uniqueness for a form that's repeated several times on one particular page in my application, and I've added a custom validator, but it seems to not be firing.I had wondered if `mat-error` was set up incorrectly, but it's working as expected when a required error is present. Code is as follows:

network.service.ts(the previousNames value is initialized and declared as an empty arry in this file):

```js
userNameValidator(userControl: AbstractControl) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.validateUserName(userControl.value)) {
        resolve({ userNameNotAvailable: true });
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

validateUserName(userName: string) {
  return this.previousNames.indexOf(userName) > -1;
}
```

duplicate - name.directive.ts:

```js
import { Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Validator,
  AbstractControl,
  NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { NetworkService } from '../services/network.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appValidateUserName]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ValidateUserNameDirective),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class ValidateUserNameDirective implements Validator {
  constructor(private network: NetworkService) { }

  validate(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any }> {
    return this.network.userNameValidator(control);
  }
}
```

network - card.component.html:

```html
<form #personForm="ngForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <p>
        <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
          <mat-label>Person Initials/Nickname</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text" name="name" minLength="2" id="name{{ count }}" [(ngModel)]="person.name"
            appValidateUserName required />
          <mat-error *ngIf="personForm.controls['name']?.errors?.appValidateUserName">
            That name has already been used for another network member</mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="personForm.controls['name']?.errors?.required">
            A name is required</mat-error>
          <mat-hint>Enter a full name, nickname, initials or whatever is more
            memorable.</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
      </p>
```

What's not shown here is the this.network.previousNames value being updated every time a new card is added to the page.

Comment: Few questions: 1. Why you need setTimeout in the network service? 2. Is Network service & Validator directive part of the root (app) module?

Comment: !)  I was wondering about the setTimeout, that's an artifact from the code example I got it from, removing it seems to have no effect 2) Yes, the network service definitely is. From what I understand of the custom validator, the provide array in that code should take care of registering it